# Explanation on window.getComputedStyle and why Chrome handles it differently

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, web-standards

Since Chrome Stable landed v.**33.0.1750.117**, the logic of window.getComputedStyle has changed from other browsers. Fiddle of code below: http://jsfiddle.net/HD4bD/17/

Can anyone explain what changed and what is the 'correct' ruling on this?

Given the following:

#### HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="normal"></div>
    <div class="display-none"></div>
    <div class="visibility-hidden"></div>
</body>
```

#### CSS

```
.normal:before {
    content: "NORMAL: "
}

.display-none:before {
    content: "DISPLAY-NONE: ";
    display: none;
}

.visibility-hidden:before {
    content: "VIS-HIDDEN: "
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

#### JS

```
var $ = document.querySelector.bind(document),
    pass = "This text should have 1 or more labels before it",
    fail = "The label is missing.  Something's wrong.",
    normalContent = getB4Content('.normal'),
    dNoneContent = getB4Content('.display-none'),
    vHideContent = getB4Content('.visibility-hidden');

function getB4Content(selector){
     return window.getComputedStyle($(selector),':before').getPropertyValue('content');
}



$('.normal').innerHTML = normalContent === '' ? fail : normalContent + pass;

$('.display-none').innerHTML = dNoneContent === '' ? fail : dNoneContent + pass;

$('.visibility-hidden').innerHTML = vHideContent === '' ? fail : vHideContent + pass;
```

#### OUTPUT

**Firefox v27:**
NORMAL: "NORMAL: "This text should have 1 or more labels before it
"DISPLAY-NONE: "This text should have 1 or more labels before it
noneThis text should have 1 or more labels before it

**IE 11**
NORMAL: "NORMAL: "This text should have 1 or more labels before it
"DISPLAY-NONE: "This text should have 1 or more labels before it
noneThis text should have 1 or more labels before it

**Chrome v33**
NORMAL: "NORMAL: "This text should have 1 or more labels before it
The label is missing. Something's wrong.
The label is missing. Something's wrong.

Comment: [Another question on what appears to be the same topic.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646061/getting-pseudo-element-content-in-chrome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this is a [reported Chromium bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=236603).

Comment: well I guess that explains it =).